# PHP array_filter on OR operator

Tags: php, filtering, array-filter

I'm using `array_filter` to apply an array of filters to an array of data. The function call looks something like 
`$data = array_filter($tmpData, function($row) use $filterData { ... });`.
This works just fine if I am filtering where the logic for each filter is AND. But if I want to filter between two values using OR, then I get a little shaky on how to handle this because each filter can also have a nested set of more filters which would recursively call the filtering function. The filters are formatted like this:

```
$filter = array(
  'logic' => 'AND',
  'filters' => array(
    array('field' => $myFieldName1, 'operator' => $filterOperator1, 'value' => $myValue1),
    array(
      'logic' => 'OR',
      'filters' => array(
        array('field' => $myFieldName2, 'operator' => $filterOperator2, 'value' => $myValue2),
        array('field' => $myFieldName3, 'operator' => $filterOperator3, 'value' => $myValue3)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

You can see a slightly trimmed-down version of my function in action here. It only implements one filter operator besides 'equal to'. https://www.tehplayground.com/FiPHxwDNJWdKq4hM

Appreciate any help with making the OR portion of this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think a recursive function will get you there. First, I'm going to mock some data similar to yours but probably a little bit simpler:

```php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->a = 5;
$obj->b = 2;
$obj->c = 9;

$filter = array(
    'logic' => 'AND',
    'filters' => array(
        array('field' => 'a', 'operator' => '===', 'value' => 5),
        array(
            'logic' => 'OR',
            'filters' => array(
                array('field' => 'b', 'operator' => '===', 'value' => 6),
                array('field' => 'c', 'operator' => '<', 'value' => 10),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then, we're write a recursive function. I'm using PHP 8's `match` which makes this very succinct, but you might need to change that based on your PHP version. See the code comments for more details. It isn't the most efficient, but it should get the job done.

```php
function process(string $logic, array $filters, object $obj): bool
{
    // For an AND, all things must be true, so if we're given 5 things, all 5 must be true.
    // For an OR, only one needs to be true.
    $targetCount = 'AND' === $logic ? count($filters) : 1;

    // How many items were true
    $currentCount = 0;
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {

        // The sub-array is a grouping, grab parts, process, and if true, increment our local counter
        if (array_key_exists('logic', $filter)) {
            if (process($filter['logic'], $filter['filters'], $obj)) {
                $currentCount++;
            }

            // For a sub-array, don't process anything else
            continue;
        }

        // Grab array items as variables just for ease of use
        $field = $filter['field'];
        $operator = $filter['operator'];
        $value = $filter['value'];

        // Match on the operator. For lower versions of PHP a switch(true) or just an if could be used, too.
        $result = match ($operator) {
            '===' => $obj->$field === $value,
            '==' => $obj->$field == $value,
            '>=' => $obj->$field >= $value,
            '>' => $obj->$field > $value,
            '<=' => $obj->$field <= $value,
            '<' => $obj->$field < $value,
        };

        // If success, increment our counter
        if ($result) {
            $currentCount++;

            // If we've reach our target, return success
            // This could also just be "if process = OR"
            if ($currentCount === $targetCount) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // See if we met the final condition outside of the loop
    return $currentCount === $targetCount;
}
```

And lastly, an example of invoking it. With recursive functions, you usually have to determine if you want to make the whole function try and determine if it is the first iteration and setup things up, or if you want to pass in the setup so that each iteration runs identically, and I've done the latter.

```php
echo process($filter['logic'], $filter['filters'], $obj) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

And online sample is here: https://3v4l.org/Hu0CY#v8.0.8